# Android allowed but not BlackBerry?

Tags: discussion

There is an Android Enthusiast proposal which was allowed to grow, despite its duplication with the Mobile Phone proposal, and has reached beta phase. When an essentially equivalent site for BlackBerry was proposed it was closed as a duplicate on day one. Why?

Comment: RIM's market share is declining...A Blackberry Q&A site would be short-lived and few members - at least after a while.

Comment: Mistake #1 - these aren't forums.

Comment: @Joel my mistake for using the word "forum" but the question still applies.

Comment: @studiohack ha ha, very funny. There are far more BlackBerry than iPhone out there, and RIM's stock is rising.

Comment: @DJ: all that is being shaken up by Windows Phone, Android, and iPhone.  just saying. I have no desire to start a flame war. :-)

Comment: That was a strange comment for someone who didn't want to start a flame war.

Comment: Anyway I don't see a declining market share as a good reason to close the proposal. I'm not owner or enthusiast of BB so I have no interest on this site but if Android has its own site, my logic states that BB should have yours.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think the Android site was a bad idea.  In the same way Stack Overflow proper is awesome at handling questions on .Net, java, php, sql server, oracle, mysql, etc all in one place, I think (almost) any site that focuses on a specific brand like Android is misguided.  I know there are exceptions, but in the vast majority of cases where you see a brand-focused site you should instead look at the market that brand is targeted towards.

That said, Android encompasses more than just smart phones. There are tablets out already and rumors that Google will eventually push android for use in netbooks.  Who knows from there.  In other words, I think the Android site would be better served to have targeted something like "portable, internet capable sub-computers".

But the main point is that Android is broad enough to be distinct from a site targeted specifically at smart phones.  Blackberry, on the other hand, is smart phone all the way.  While RIM is known to be working on a tablet, it's offering is expected to run a completely different operating system from the Blackberry and be essentially a completely different platform.

In a nutshell, any question you could possibly ask about blackberry would almost certainly be appropriate on the smart phones site as well.  The same is not true of Android.

Comment: While I totally agree with first paragraph since the Android site was created I can't see why a BB site couldn't be created. Maybe the proposal could be changed to RIM platform. I have no personal interest on that proposal and I closed many proposals on Ara51 but I disagree with this close. In fact I would like to see fewer proposals but selected in a fair way.

Comment: @bigown - part of the problem is that there is no rim platform. Their upcoming tablet for example will not carry the blackberry brand and is going to use a completely different system from their smartphones.  What we really needed was one site for all portable sub-computer internet devices.

Comment: Yes, and there is no Apple platform, but Apple has its site. All the problem is the double standard.

Comment: There is an apple portable platform - Apples phones, iPod Touch, and Tablet (iPad) all use the same operating system and sdk.  But, again, my thought is that the Apple site shouldn't exist, either.  This all belongs under one umbrella.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot more hacking, programming, and user activity surrounding the Android platform than the blackberry platform.  It is a very open source system.  The users are more likely to be hackers and programmers at this point in time than the users of blackberries are likely to be.

Blackberry consists of a lot of users, and there are a lot of programmers, but not as many enthusiasts actively hacking away at the platform and system.  As a closed platform, it doesn't encourage users who want to explore the guts of the system.  Further, there's a lot of information out there already - it's a mature platform, and there's not as much need to have a site that can collect and disseminate new information.

In fact, iOS devices have a lot of the same drawbacks as blackberry has - closed, lots of existing sites saturate the market, etc.  There is more hacking going on here, but as much of it is against Apple's policy it would create significant friction in the community.

Comment: Although a bit subjective and not perfect this is the best argument for me. Area51 has lots of iPhone, iOS e similar proposals on beta or definition phase. BB or RIM platform can't have 1 proposal. This is strange to me.

Comment: @bigown - There shouldn't be any iPhone or iOS proposals at Area51 in any phase. User-level iPhone and iOS questions are welcome at Apple.SE, while code-level iPhone and iOS questions belong at SO.

Comment: @Dori: Yes, I totally agree. There **shouldn't** but there are. Apple.SE and SO is enough to me. Why RIM can't have a proposal? I'm not a RIM customer, actually I hate their products :) I just don't like the messy on Area51.

Answer (score 2):

Android Enthusiasts is past commitment and is in beta meaning [it has already launched](https://android.stackexchange.com/).  Android was here *before* the mobile phone proposals.  If the mobile phone proposals had reached beta(meaning the site was launched)before Android Enthusiasts then I have no doubt an Android proposal would have been closed.

Also, there is a difference between Android and Blackberry.  Blackberry, AFIAK, is solely used for phones and is thus a clear subset of the mobile phones proposal.  Android, OTOH, is used for phones, tablets, even some computers, and there is a rumor that it might power TV and some household appliances soon.  Would all that Android talk be on-topic on a mobile phones site?  Personally, I don't think so.

Comment: The problem is that has lots of double standards on proposals. Some follow this thought, some stay open even when a similar proposal is in beta.

Comment: @Bigown: Perhaps someone should ask Jeff to lay down the law?

Comment: Perhaps, but I think this discussion here could open the eyes and community take the right way.

Comment: @Bigown:What are you saying the right way is?

Comment: Follow a single criteria. Community could decides what to do looking for the past actions. I know it's hard because community is not a single entity but it's possible with conscientization. If not, moderators should correct that.